# Why are heatmaps on qgis 2.8.1 produced in the wrong CRS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I noticed that the heatmap calculation on the new upgrade version of qgis is given the raster map without any coordinate system.

Have you got the same problem?

Comment: Yes, looks like a local (0,0) system in QGIS 2.8.1. Works in QGIS 2.6.

Comment: This is a [known bug](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12264) in 2.8.1, which should be fixed in 2.8.2.

Comment: This looks like the same issue I'm having, good to see it's being addressed: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137891/qgis-2-8-raster-layers-moved

Comment: It looks like the heatmaps are being referenced in image coordinates, not the coords of the SRS.

Answer (score 7):

This is a [known bug](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/12264) in 2.8.1, which is (according to the tracker) slated for fixing in 2.8.2.

As an alternative, you can use v.kernel from the Processing toolbox.

Comment: You can also use the on-the-fly heatmap generator on the layer style of the properties dialog.

Comment: What is this "on-the-fly heatmap generator"? Are you talking about layer blending modes on the point layer?

Answer (score 7):

Until it get fixed You can do as follows with one more step:

1. Calculate heatmap as normal
2. Create new raster with **Raster >
   Projections > Warp(Reproject)** - leave the original projection
3. Magic - the new raster is exactly where it belongs :)

I got this answer from @Joseph who gave helpful comment in the duplicate thread: [QGIS 2.8 Raster Layers Moved](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137891/qgis-2-8-raster-layers-moved) and encouraged me to post it here.