# QGIS heatmap misplaced over dataset

Tags: qgis, heat-map

First of all I'm a complete noob when it comes to QGIS so maybe thats the reason why I cannot find anything on this on google (or is this due to the 2.8.1 compatebility issue?).

My issue is that when I create the heatmap the location of the heatmap is off compared to the data. I've checked the CRS and all match (project CRS, data CRS AND the heatmap CRS). I've redone several tutorials several times and started several times from scratch but somehow it keeps giving me the data on the wrong location :-(.

[image: printscreen of QGIS]

Comment: Apparently, it's a [known bug](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137770/why-are-heatmaps-on-qgis-2-8-1-produced-in-the-wrong-crs). But there are a couple of alternatives you could try from the given post.

Comment: Hi joseph, thanks for your quick reply!
good point: it's known and being solved
bad thing: GRASS does not work. re-installing QGIS did not work. QGIS does not seem to be able to find the GRASS install?

Comment: Most welcome Bas :) I remembered seeing a similar problem before.

Comment: It works with 2.6 - just install that version too until it gets fixed.