# Heat Map not showing up QGIS

Tags: qgis, heat-map

I'm fairly new to QGIS and I'm trying to use Heatmap.  I should be doing every thing correct. But when I click OK for it to generate a heatmap, there is no Heatmap at all (nothing changes).

For the points I created a New Shapefile and then I used "Add Feature" button to add many points to the map.  The only thing I can think might be causing the problem is I'm adding points to map the wrong way perhaps.

I have the latest version of QGIS 2.8.1

When i zoom out to the world view I can see a giant 1/4 of a heat map circle at the bottom right of the map. So i was thinking the map coordinates (CRS) might be different, but they are really set to the same map coordinates (CRS). So I don't know what is going on.

EDIT:
It also was doing this in an older version I had, so last night I download the latest version (maybe should not have) hoping it would help and nothing changed.

Comment: Are you using WGS84 (4326)?

Comment: It is said reported bug of this version and will be fixed in 2.8.2. There is similar post on this site and it has a work around..
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/137770/why-are-heatmaps-on-qgis-2-8-1-produced-in-the-wrong-crs

Comment: I'm using: Selected CRS (ESPG:4269, NAD83)

Comment: Because of your edit, this was automatically nominated for reopening. For the moment I've voted to leave it closed. If you do want to reopen it, please edit your post to include/tag the version you were originally using (assuming you want to go back to that). You can mention that you tried 2.8.1 but you don't believe the problem is the same as [link to question] because it's happening in a prior version. If you want to stick with 2.8.1 and wait it out or follow the workarounds, we'll likely leave this as closed.

Comment: It will be fine to leave it closed, I'll probably just wait until the new release.

Answer (score 0):

IF you open that heatmap in ArcGIS, you will see it shows correctly. I check the metadata. Its layer extent is base on row and column numbers instead of coordinates. Still ArcGIS can understand how to show it by reading origin information and cell size values.

Comment: The OP does not mention ArcGIS.  Is this an answer or a comment?

Comment: I am explaining that there is nothing wrong with the result of this QGIS process by checking the raster with another software (ArcGIS).